# Vue js how to set a default router path to navigate when the web app loads

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I have a project it's routing strucher is like this.

```
1. /
2. admin-panel/:type
    2.1 create-user
    2.2 update-user
    2.3 etc...
3. forgot password
```

My problem is if someone come to the `admin-panel/:type`,he has to route to the create-user
by default.

I used a tricky way for this which is create root route under the `admin-panel/:type`

like this

```
2.admin-panel
 2.1 /
 2.2 create-user
```

But this doesn't work this time since the **admin-panel** has a parameter called **type**.

I want if someone comes to the `admin-panel` he should directed to the `create-user` by default. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I've to add redirect property to the `admin-panel` route.

Answer (score 0):

Personally for these cases I use an `afterEach` hook in the routes file:

```
router.afterEach((to, from) => {
  let exist = false

  for (let i in this.a.options.routes) {
    if (this.a.options.routes[i].name === to.name) {
      exist = true
    }
  }

  if (!exist) {
    this.a.push({
      name: from.name
    })
  }
})
```

You can use another hook as `beforeEach` (I do not remember exactly why we use after). Basically the goal is to go through the list of routes, if it does not exist, it returns you to the route you are currently on, which really means that you do not notice any changes, it just does not change the route.